# How can use JavaScript variable in mssql query

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server

```
<script language="javascript">
   var rowcode=0;
   function myclick(id)
   {
     if (rowcode!=0){
        document.getElementById(rowcode).style.background="";
        rowcode=id;
        document.getElementById(id).style.background="yellow";
        }
   }
</script>     

<a onClick="ShowDiv('<?php $result=Select("select * from CourseTeacher where lessonID IN(select lessonID from Lesson where place IN(select place from Place where id=  ))");
```

I dont know how can set the value of rowcode to id?

Comment: Do you know how to run hard-coded queries that do not use variables?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  So that we can answer your question properly, could you describe in more detail what this code is for, what you have tried and what is the goal of your code in general?  A good starting place to learn more about Stack Overflow is the [About] page.  If you ever have any questions about Stack Overflow, visit the [help] first.  Good luck!

Comment: Learn the difference between server-side and client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Ajax for that. Get the value of "rowcode" through ajax and then use in the sql query!!

Comment: Thanks. but i dont know how can use javascript variable in xajax.This is part of my xajax function:   
function ShowDiv()
{
 
 $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
 
require ("./DataAccessLayer.php");
 Connect();
 
$result=Select("select * from CourseTeacher where lessonID IN(select lessonID from Lesson where place IN(select place from Place where id=  ))");